# When taking a photosphere picture with a Google Camera app, how can I get a pointer to which photo is missing?

Tags: photos, google-camera

When taking a photosphere picture with a Google Camera app, I sometimes have issues to find which photo(s) are missing to complete the photosphere.  How can I get a pointer to which photo is missing?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the Google Camera app UI doesn't provide a way to customize the overlay.   The only way to see what is missing is to keep moving your camera around until it shows you the blue circles indicating the missing frames.

In my experience, it's usually spots right around the zenith (directly up) or nadir (directly down) that are most easily missed.